# ORA-01422 error on recompilation/revalidation (NOT EXECUTION) of package/trigger

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to grant execution on a package to another schema.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PP.PKG_PROF TO PPSERVICE;
```

Looks like Oracle attempts to recompile/revalidate the package before making the grant.  However it is failing with the following error:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PP.PKG_PROF TO PPSERVICE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of PP.PKG_PROF
ORA-20000: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 83
04045. 00000 -  "errors during recompilation/revalidation of %s.%s"
*Cause:    This message indicates the object to which the following
       errors apply.  The errors occurred during implicit
       recompilation/revalidation of the object.    
*Action:   Check the following errors for more information, and
       make the necessary corrections to the object.
```

But if i look at the code on line 83, it executes the following query:

```
select 'x' into vtemp 
from cust_field_vals
where cust_fields = vin_cust_fields
and userid = vin_user_id;
```

vin_cust_fields and vin_user_id are parameter based values that are provided when the procedure in the package gets called.

My question is: what in the world is oracle doing?  I understand that a "SELECT INTO"
can theoretically return more than the requested number of rows (which would need to be one in this case), but since it doesn't know what my vin parameters are, how can it make that assessment?  Why is a recompilation/revalidation throwing what essentially amounts to an exception for a data anomaly which it shouldn't even be looking at for what I'm trying to do (ie: i'm not trying to actually execute the procedure).

This is not the first time I've seen this, and if I remember correctly, I even think it's happened on recompilation of triggers as well (not when inserting data).

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `BEFORE GRANT` or `AFTER GRANT` DDL trigger in your database?

Comment: It is possible (we had a BEFORE DDL to capture CREATE/REPLACE/DROP/ALTERS) but I can't see it as I dont' have SYS access and our DBA left the company.  I can say that only 2 out of our 20 packages are generating this error (trying to refresh our UAT environment from PROD).  I'm just not sure if that BEFORE DDL ON DATABASE was ever moved into UAT.  So, if it were something at the SYS level, wouldn't the exception be generated when compiling all of those other packages too?

Comment: I can't possibly say without knowing the source of the trigger and the details of your database. My guess is that the "line 83" is a reference to a line in the DDL trigger, not in the package, and that you're being bitten by a bug in the DDL trigger. Best of luck.

Comment: now i'm confused.  using sql developer if i went into the package body and tried to compile there, it was generating the same error.  however, i randomly compiled the package spec first, then the package body and it worked fine.  the grants then went through without an error.  no clue why it was generating such a weird error.  i guess oracle couldnt tell me the spec was out of whack too and was choking on jsut the body?!?

Comment: +1 - glad you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, the problem was the package i was trying to GRANT execute on was "invalid" even though there were no actual code errors.  Compiling the body first was generating the above mentioned error.  If I manually compiled the package spec first, then the body, the error went away and the grant executed normally.  No code errors were present in the package, it was just stuck in an invalid state it could not get out of.

Comment: i'll accept my answer in 2 days when stackoverflow lets me.  in the meantime, consider this ANSWERED!